# Questions on Continuous Function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I know that it is very obvious that intuitively, a continuous function cannot have any gap in between. However, I am having difficulty proving it. Normally, in textbook and also in my real analysis, it is said that a if a function is continuous, it must satisfy f(c) exists for all $c\in [a,b]$ without a rigorous proof. According to the definition of continuity given in my textbook:

$$\text{f is continuous at c if, given any number } \epsilon > 0, \text{there exists } \delta > 0 \text{ such that if x is any point in A satisfying } |x-c|<\delta, \text{ then |f(x)-f(c)|} < \epsilon$$

To me, this pre assumes that f(c) exists, else how can I use the definition? Hence, can someone provide a rigorous proof of the fact that if f(k) $(k \in [a,b]$) does not exist, then f cannot be continuous in [a,b].

Comment: If it doesn't exist, then it doesn't fit the definition. Hence not continuous. You simply need to check whether or not it satisfies the definition.

Comment: There is a more general definition of continuity (see Rudin, Real and complex analysis, third edition, 1.2 Definition). In the present case f(x) is continuous provided f^(-1)(V) is an open set for every open V from R. Thus the existence of f(c) seems to be contained in the definition. See also Wikipedia.

Comment: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a continuous function. Let $x,c\in X$ and let $|x-c|<\delta$. Now assume that $f(c)$ does not exist. Then we cannot have $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ because $f(c)$ does not exist. Hence a function cannot be continuous where it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to give us the domain. If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(k)$ doesn't exist for some $k\in [a,b]$, then $f$ is not a function. In this case it doesn't make sense to talk about continuity.